# LongClick status stuck

Tags: android

If I 'click', it will print "click". However, once I 'long click' it will only print "long click", regardless of the length.

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);

ll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
        System.out.println("click");
    }
});

ll.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        v.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        System.out.println("long click");                   
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                }
                return false;
            }                      
        });                     
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by your code. Ultimately, what are trying to do?

Comment: When I long click the LinearLayout, I want to eventually capture the coordinates. As is, after I long click once, it will capture the coordinates anytime I click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just an TouchListener? It will record the time on `ACTION_DOWN` and if the `ACTION_UP` time is long enough pull the coordinates from the MotionEvent.

```
ll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    Calendar down;
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            down = Calendar.getInstance();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // Only continue if longer than 2 seconds
            if(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - down.getTimeInMillis() > 2000) {
                // Touch coordinates: event.getX(), event.getY()
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

possibly change:

```
ll.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){
    @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        v.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            System.out.println("long click");                   
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            }
        return false;
        }                      
        });                     
    return true;
    }
});
```

to

```
ll.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        System.out.println("long click");  
        v.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                }
                return false;
            }                      
        });                     
        return true;
    }
});
```

this way it will print "long click" when its received a long click and not a touch event which you "setup" after